# Recommended books for studying Algebra, Geometry and Calculus

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry, book-recommendation

What would be the best books covering topics like Algebra, Geometry (Euclidean geometry) and Calculus? Which classics can be recommended (classics in the sense of historical works that have been widely disseminated throughout the history of mathematics, for example: Euclid's Elements)?

I would like to have an overview of the main classics that influenced paradigms and changes in the history of mathematics (I understand that reading can be considered difficult, but I am willing to risk it).

Objective: Historical Curiosity.

Comment: Depends very much on the intended level (high school, college, graduate?), how you are studying (along or with a teacher), the kind of curriculum you intend to follow, etc. Also, classics may be rather expensive (Apostol for Calculus for instance).

Comment: Rice University has some free books on their https://openstax.org/subjects/math OpenStax platform. They are intended to bridge the gap between high school and college so that students start at a comparable level. They are more school books than scientific books, but it is a free source for you to check where you stand with your knowledge.

Comment: Oops. I think my question was not very objective regarding the context. I'll fix that.

Comment: Dover Publications, formerly Dover Press, has an enormous array of older textbooks of science and math at very low prices.

Comment: My goal is to have an overview of the main classics that influenced paradigms and changes in the history of mathematics. I understand that reading can be considered difficult due to a number of factors, however, I would like to have an idea of which works had this impact on history.

Answer (score 0):

Linear algebra by Gilbert Strang is a very standard book on Linear algebra.

Engineering mathematics by BS Grewal, McGraw Hill Publications is also a very good book which covers a great deal of mathematical topics you have mentioned.

For geometry, please let me know what field you need. Like Euclidean geometry, coordinate geometry, differential geometry or whatever. I can suggest you books only after that. See, geometry covers many aspects of mathematics and no one book can cover all aspects of it. Please be specific.

Answer (score 0):

For undergraduate abstract algebra you may try the following:

1. Fundamentals of Abstract Algebra by Malik, Moderson, Sen (very nice and useful book for concept making).
2. Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Joseph Gallian ( provides a lot of exercises).
3. Abstract algebra by Dummit Foote.
4. Algebra by Artin.
5. Algebra (3-volumes) by Jacobson (A classic one).
6. Topics in abstract algebra by Herstein.

For linear algebra, I suggest the following

1. Linear algebra by Fredberg.
2. Linear algebra by Gilbert Strang.
3. Advanced Linear algebra by Roman.
4. Linear algebra by Serge Lang.

For calculas some good books are:

1. Thomas Calculas.
2. Stewart Calculas.

For studying single and multivariate calculas these two books are very useful.
Thank you.

Comment: Wrong level of algebra, I would bet.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Also, none seem to qualify as "classics that influenced paradigms and changes in the history of mathematics".